# Why is the font-size larger than normal?

Tags: gnome

Recently, UI font sizes have been larger than expected. See the top bar below:

[image]

Upon enabling/re-disabling the "Large Text" setting under Universal Access, the problem resolves:

[image]

Should I report this as a bug? Is there a way to override this in Tweaks? The scaling factor is currently 1.0.

Comment: Do you have this problem on the login screen also. What happens with another (newly created) user?

Comment: In one of the answers of the link above, there is a link to the bug in launchpad.

Comment: ... and a workaround to have the scaling right after you login. Will probably be fixed quite soon.